# animating wrong listview image

Tags: android, listview

ok so I have an ExpandableListView,  I have defined all my views and everything works well. But now what I need is to have an animation when a group expands and collapse.

So I have an image in the header of the group xml, then I write.

```
listView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, long id) {


            TextView tv1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtGroupName);
            ImageView tv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.dropdownarrow);

            Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(TabHome.this,
                    R.anim.rotatearrowup);

            if (listView.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {                  

                tv.clearAnimation();                    
                a.setFillAfter(true);                   
                tv.setAnimation(a);                 
                a.start();          

                a.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        adapterSub.notifyDataSetChanged();                          
                    }
                });
            }                   

            return false;
        }
    });
```

now when I click on a group header or the view, it animates the wrong view. It would animate either the row below or the row above.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Or how could solve this?

Comment: Do you handle value `int groupPosition` somewhere in your code? That part of code would be interesting to see because most probably the problem is out of the given snippet.

Comment: Show us the more code, as @Mikko said, the problem is probably outside this snippet.  I even think I know what it is because I had a similar problem where images for a ListView were loaded asynchronously; the wrong row would be updated with the wrong image.

Comment: @mikko I used in a number of places in the adapter but it's not like I change the value of it. 

Where else could I do such an animation. I'm open to suggestion. Doesn't have to be this way.

Comment: @Mikko you were right. Post a solution will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you handle value int groupPosition somewhere in your code? The problem most possibly is outside this snippet.